# AWS CloudFront automatic compression doesn't work

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

Today I wanted to enable AWS CloudFront automatic compression for my S3 bucket, since Google PageSpeed Insights recommended to do so. So what I did:
- went to cloudfront, choose distribution, edited behavior settings, enabled "Compress objects automatically";
- waited for distribution to re-deploy.

After that, I checked the requests to s3 bucket from my page.

```
Request headers:

:authority:******.com
:method:GET
:path:/app.min.js
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,da;q=0.2
cache-control:no-cache
cookie:_ga=GA1.2.1335221784.1504949270; _gid=GA1.2.1414665009.1509096143
pragma:no-cache
referer:https://****.com/index.html
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36

Response headers:

age:1507
content-length:633168
content-type:application/javascript
date:Thu, 26 Oct 2017 10:05:44 GMT
etag:"45078c31177a2c0aa98e2d97b014841e"
last-modified:Thu, 26 Oct 2017 09:58:14 GMT
server:AmazonS3
status:200
via:1.1 f96185b1d69d6f85635bc2b5554da639.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id:aOflZZwZTvtfNnm2gxOQGKMxZi-MVfuiTw9YhRxswoqU84L84Z3D-Q==
x-cache:Hit from cloudfront
```

Seems like all headers that CloudFront need to make autocompression work is present, but neither the request loads faster nor the file size decreases. Google PageSpeed Tool still recommends to enable autocompression. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved. I had to invalidate cloudfront cache for the distribution, since cloudfront doesn't compress objects that is in cache already.